# Convert HTML with missing external references to epub?

Tags: html, converters, offline, epub, pandoc

I have save the web page via "save as..." in the browser as HTML file (single-file) on the disk.
http://pedrokroger.net/2012/10/using-sphinx-to-write-books/

Now, I'd like to convert it to epub.

`pandoc -f html -t epub -S -R -s Using\ Sphinx\ to\ Write\ Technical\ Books\ -\ Pedro\ Kroger.html -o Using\ Sphinx\ to\ Write\ Technical\ Books\ -\ Pedro\ Kroger.epub`

But pandoc throws an error:

`pandoc: /images/pages/profile.png: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

Is there a option to tell pandoc to ignore all external references and just convert the bare text?

This would be very convenient!

Comment: Maybe you should ask this question at the [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/pandoc-discuss) forum, or ask a feature request at [Pandoc's Github repository](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues)?